# Read/Write into Azure Blob from .NET Core Web API using Azur Ad Auth

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, .net-5

I am trying to incorporate blob upload from my API. So created the storage account and container.

And the authentication mode is set to Azure AD. In our Org policy we are restricted to use connection string

[image]

But 90% of the tutorials on upload/download from blob is using Connectionstring
[.NET Core Blob access](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2020/08/09/uploading-files-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-and-asp.net-core/)

But since mine is Azure AD based I am really stuck how to proceed with

I tried this way and very late I found it wont support in .net 5

```
        var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(_StorageAuth.AccessToken, TokenRenewerAsync, null, tokenExpiry);
        string blobcontainer = "blob-container-dev-dv1";
        string storageName = "apllmyappdevuksst";

        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential), storageName, null, true);


        
        //Uri accountUri = new Uri(storageAccount.BlobStorageUri.ToString());
        //BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient(accountUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I really dont know what to do next for file upload into blob from .NET core 5

The token and everything is getting correctly for the storage scope

Comment: My sample app might help here: https://github.com/juunas11/managedidentity-filesharing/blob/ff5c234a49061d46deb3d031b9a95bcb97f451a1/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityFileSharingDemo/Services/AzureBlobStorageService.cs#L37

Comment: Have you tried [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobServiceClient__ctor_System_Uri_Azure_Core_TokenCredential_Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClientOptions_) constructor of `BlobServiceClient`?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi it says use DefaultAzureCredential

Comment: `DefaultAzureCredential` is a type of `TokenCredential` so that can be used. I would recommend reading up about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet to get a better understanding of how it actually works.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried that which is something I commented because I have no idea what to do after. But will try that again..

Comment: Oh, once you have the BlobServiceClient, you can use the same code as mentioned in the link you shared. It is going to be exactly the same from that point onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea, this was so straight. Sharing for those with similar requirement
Thanks a lot for @Gaurav Matri for pointing it out

```
 BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
  BlobContainerClient containerClient = client.GetBlobContainerClient("container");

   string f = Path.GetFileName(filename);
   BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(f);

   var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ADOData", "Before2020.txt");
   using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(path);

   await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
   uploadFileStream.Close()
```